# How to return an error from a method inside a method in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am running a method inside another method in Meteor.js, and I want to return the error to the client, but I'm getting this error on console:

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'validarCupon':
```

This is the Method I'm actually calling on the client:

```
Meteor.methods({
  hacerPedido:function(){
    var carrito = CarritoUsuario.findOne({idUsuario: Meteor.userId()});
    var cupon = carrito.cupon;
    //Texto y lógica del cupón
    Meteor.call("validarCupon", cupon.codigo, function(error, result){
      if(error){
        throw new Meteor.Error("cupon-invalido", error.reason);
      }
    });
    return creditoUsuario;
  }
});
```

And what I want to do is get the error from the method called 'validarCupon' and pass that to the client that is invoking the method 'hacerPedido'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the inner method asynchronously, which prevents you from throwing anything back to the caller because the `return creditoUsario` is all likelihood called *before* the throw.

Hopefully though, you don't need to do this asynchronously, in which case you can simply do:

```
Meteor.methods({
  hacerPedido:function(){
    var carrito = CarritoUsuario.findOne({idUsuario: Meteor.userId()});
    var cupon = carrito.cupon;
    //Texto y lógica del cupón
    Meteor.call("validarCupon", cupon.codigo);
    return creditoUsuario;
  }
});
```

Because exceptions bubble up. So any exception in the validarCupon method will be thrown to the client automatically.

If you do need that method to run asynchronously, then you'll need to change your logic a little, because once the `return` happens (the method body ends) there is no more basis to communicate back to the client on.

Also, if you go with the solution above, I would recommend not even using a method call within the server, but make it simple function.

Comment: This solves the problem I was having, luckily I don't need to run them asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

In the meteor [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-call) for `Meteor.call`, it says on server-side, you don't need a callback and the meteor call will be synchronous.

> On the server
>
> On the server, you don't have to pass a callback — the method call will simply > block until the method is complete, returning a result or throwing an > exception, just as if you called the function directly:
>
> // Synchronous call on the server with no callback
>   var result = Meteor.call('commentOnPost', comment, postId);

So, I think you should do something like this,

```
Meteor.methods({
  hacerPedido:function(){
    var carrito = CarritoUsuario.findOne({idUsuario: Meteor.userId()});
    var cupon = carrito.cupon;
    //Texto y lógica del cupón
    try {
        var result = Meteor.call("validarCupon", cupon.codigo);
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Meteor.Error("cupon-invalido", error.reason);
    }
    return creditoUsuario;
  }
});
```